# How to count values over different thresholds per column in Pandas dataframe groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My goal is for a dataset similar to the example below, to group by [s_num, ip, f_num, direction] and then filter the score columns using separate thresholds and count how many values are above the threshold.

```
    id  s_num   ip  f_num   direction   algo_1_x    algo_2_x    algo_1_score    algo_2_score
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 X   -4.63   -4.45   0.624356    0.664009
15  19.0    0.0 2.0 0.0 X   -5.44   -5.02   0.411217    0.515843
16  20.0    0.0 2.0 0.0 X   -12.36  -5.09   0.397237    0.541112
20  24.0    0.0 2.0 1.0 X   -4.94   -5.15   0.401744    0.526032
21  25.0    0.0 2.0 1.0 X   -4.78   -4.98   0.386410    0.564934
22  26.0    0.0 2.0 1.0 X   -4.89   -5.03   0.394326    0.513896
24  28.0    0.0 2.0 2.0 X   -4.78   -5.00   0.420078    0.521993
25  29.0    0.0 2.0 2.0 X   -4.91   -5.14   0.407355    0.485878
26  30.0    0.0 2.0 2.0 X   11.83   -4.97   0.392242    0.659122
27  31.0    0.0 2.0 2.0 X   -4.73   -5.07   0.377011    0.524774
​
```

the result should look something like:

Each entry in algo_i column is the # of values in the group larger than the corresponding threshold

[image: each entry in algo_i column is the # of values in the group larger than the corresponding threshold]

So far I tried first grouping, and applying custom aggregation like so:

```
def count_success(x,thresh):
    return ((x > thresh)*1).sum()

thresholds=[0.1,0.2]
df.groupby(attr_cols).agg({f'algo_{i+1}_score':count_success(thresh) for i, thresh in enumerate(thresholds)})
```

but this results in an error :

> count_success() missing 1 required positional argument: 'thresh'

So, how can I pass another argument to a function using .agg( )? or is there an easier way to do it using some pandas function?

Comment: In terms of the current error, you can use a lambda: `lambda x: count_success(x, thresh)` instead, or define a partial function: `from functools import partial`, then use `partial(count_success, thresh=thresh)`

Comment: The problem is that `.agg` expects a callable, but using `count_success(thresh)` already (wrongly) attempts to call the count_success function before the aggregation even starts, which is where your error is coming from.

Comment: I did not test whether it results in your expected output however :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could apply all the thresholding *before* you groupby, and then aggregate using `.sum` instead

Comment: Thanks! Tried using both lambda and partial function, both give the the desired output.
Which one is a better practice?

Comment: Partial is a paradigm from functional programming; if you're already using that a lot, then I would suggest going with that. Otherwise, using functools might feel a bit out of place, and a lambda might be easier and more clear.

Comment: If possible, I would try to apply thresholding before the groupby, so you can just use .sum(), something similar to the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Named aggregation does not allow extra parameter to be passed to your function. You can use numpy boardcasting:

```py
attr_cols = ["s_num", "ip", "f_num", "direction"]
score_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.match("algo_\d+_score")]

# Convert everything to numpy to prepare for broadcasting
score = df[score_cols].to_numpy()
threshold = np.array([0.1, 0.5])

# Raise `threshold` up 2 dimensions so that every value in `score` is
# broadcast against every value in `threshold`
mask = score > threshold[:, None, None]

# Assemble the result
row_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[attr_cols])
col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([threshold, score_cols], names=["threshold", "algo"])

result = (
    pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(mask), index=row_index, columns=col_index)
    .groupby(attr_cols)
    .sum()
)
```

Result:

```
threshold                          0.1                       0.5             
algo                      algo_1_score algo_2_score algo_1_score algo_2_score
s_num ip  f_num direction                                                    
0.0   0.0 0.0   X                    1            1            1            1
      2.0 0.0   X                    2            2            0            2
          1.0   X                    3            3            0            3
          2.0   X                    4            4            0            3
```